# Run, execute or issue a command?

Tags: word-usage

Which of these three word combinations is the most correct in instructions for computer users?

- run a command,
- execute a command,
- issue a command.

I've found examples of all of these combinations:

- "run this command" — https://pytorch.org ;
- "issue the following command" — https://tensorflow.org/install/install_linux ;
- "execute the command" — https://tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/programmers_guide/debugger .

Comment: I might refer to *running* or *executing* (but not *issuing*) a ***program***, but most likely I'd ***enter a command** [-line]*.

Comment: There are examples of all of the combinations in the Internet:
"run this command" — http://pytorch.org/ ;
"issue the following command" — https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux ;
"execute the command" — https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/programmers_guide/debugger .

Comment: In American English I would say run or execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usage of 'command' is the same whether it is in the context of computing or in everyday life. Therefore, 'issue' and 'execute' are both valid, though obviously mean different things.

To 'run' a command does not make sense. However, id does make sense to run a *program*.

Edit: As stated in some other comments, 'command' can be used interchangeably with 'program', but I would say this is a rarity.

Comment: Could you please explain the difference between "issue a command" and "execute a command" in the context of computing?

Comment: Think of commands as messages from a general to her army. The general 'issues' her command, a messenger 'relays' or 'transmits' the command to the army, and the army 'executes' the command. In the context of computing, the 'messenger' may be a command queue, or even a transmit buffer, or not even exist altogether.